# I want to run a .EXE File when windows boots

Tags: windows-10

I have tried using the startup folder but it takes a while to boot the app

Is there I can run it before login and before the desktop appears

Comment: Try running it as a service:  https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Windows "task" feature.
You can schedule tasks to run at any time, including at bootup.
You can manage your tasks with the taskschd.msc utility built into windows.

Tasks can run any executable files, including .exes.

Comment: If the OP wants it before Boot, then it needs to be a service. TM might be able to to do it, but services can run as or before boot.